# How can I add "time estimate" field into Jira's Create Issue Form?

Tags: jira, jira-agile

When creating an issue in Jira v7.3.6 (e.g. Task/ Story/ Epic) there is no "time estimate" field. Is it possible to add it there?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

JIRA calls forms *screens*.

[You can read about how to add a field to a screen here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/adminjiraserver071/defining-a-screen-802592587.html).

Note that to JIRA groups together the time fields into one thing called *time tracking*. So you will be looking to add time tracking in and this will display original estimate, remaining and time logged.